# Hook in woocommerce on subscription expiration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I create an Hook in woocommerce (wordpress) to be able to trigger a function when a subscription expires?

Something like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_expired', 'my_function', 10, 1);

function my_function($order_id) {
    echo "yeahhhh";
}
```

UPDATE

I found in the developer [doc](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) the following

> Action: 'subscription_expired'
>
> Parameters: $user_id Integer The ID of the user for whom the
>   subscription expired. $subscription_key String The key for the
>   subscription that just expired on the user’s account.
>
> Description: Triggered when a subscription reaches the end of its
>   term, if a length was set on the subscription when it was purchased.
>   This event may be triggered by either WooCommerce Subscriptions, which
>   schedules a cron-job to expire each subscription, or by the payment
>   gateway extension which can call the
>   WC_Subscriptions_Manager::expire_subscription() function directly.

Where should I place this to have it working

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are almost there. You just need to use Subscription's action hook and pass the correct parameters. This seems like a start:

```
add_action( 'subscription_expired', 'my_function', 10, 2 );

function my_function( $user_id, $subscription_key ) {
    $sub= wcs_get_subscription_from_key( $subscription_key );
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `wcs_get_subscription_from_key` is now deprecated, since version 2.0.

You can now use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_expired', 'my_on_subscription_expired', 10 );
function my_on_subscription_expired( $subscription ) {
    // do something
}
```

More hooks (and this one) at [Subscriptions Action Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/)